# How can i pass a QR code image to apple watch

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, watchkit, apple-watch

I have a QR code image in the format xamarin.forms.image created using zxing.
 My requirement is to show this QR code on apple watch. this image is saved to a global variable like below

```
stackQRCode.Children.Add(zXingBarcodeImageView);
 App.QRCodeImage = zXingBarcodeImageView
```

I am trying with wcsessionmanager.But in the UpdateApplicationContext, the image is not getting sent.
anyone with solution? What is the simplest way to achieve this?Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607138/convert-c-sharp-xamarin-forms-image-to-cgimage

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes No answer there too..i already checked

Comment: Yap I know let me vote up both

Comment: You should never change the title of the question like this!

Answer (score 1):

The Easiest way to convert a Xamarin Forms Image into a UIImage and vice versa would be byte[] conversion:

**UIImage to Byte[]:**

```
byte[] byteArray;

using (NSData imageData = originalImage.AsJPEG())
{
  byteArray = new Byte[imageData.Length];
  System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, byteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
}
```

**Byte[] to Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource:**

```
var XamImageSource=ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream
            (byteArray));
```

Now the catch is the other way around Xamarin.Forms Image/ImageSource do not expose any API's to directly get the image stream or byte[] from it.**(In my Knowledge)**

So you can use [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) instead!!

Which has an API to get the RawImage as follows

**FFImageLaoding to byte[]:**

```
var bytes = await ImageView.GetImageAsJpgAsync(); //png method also available
```

**byte[] to UIImage**

```
 var data = NSData.FromArray(byteData);
 var uiimage = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
```

Comment: originalImage is of xamarin.forms.image and AsJPEG is not available. The error getting is 'image doest not contain defiition for AsJPEG  and no accessible extension'.

Comment: Please check the part of my answer where i said the following `Now the catch is the other way around Xamarin.Forms Image/ImageSource do not expose any API's to directly get the image stream or byte[] from it.(In my Knowledge)`

Comment: What are you using to come up with the xamarin forms image? do you have a weburl or something like that of the source image?

Comment: Can you add the relevant bit to the question that would help

Comment: What does the barcodeWriter's write method return to you does it return a byteArray or a UIImage?